# Sitecore10 CLI Error "Unrecognized command or argument 'ser','push' in PowerShell window

Tags: serialization, sitecore-cli

When I try to use the below command
"dotnet sitecore ser push"

i got the below error

Unrecognized command or argument 'ser'
Unrecognized command or argument 'push'

The issue occurs because of "ser, serialization" not available under commands as shown below image.

[image: CLI command for push sitecore items]

Anyone know how to bring up the above commands in Powershell commands? Thanks in advance

Comment: which version of Sitecore are you using ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to add the serialization plugins.

`dotnet sitecore plugin add -n Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Serialization`

Comment: Don't post "thank you" comments, please. Use the voting and accept system. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267491/81631

Answer (score 0):

Add Sitecore plugins with `dotnet sitecore plugin list` command

If this is the first command after `dotnet sitecore init`, the CLI attempts to resolve and install the plugins listed in the sitecore.json file.